# Will Googlebot crawl HTTPS URLs that are encrypted by SSL?

Tags: https, googlebot, web-crawlers

This question was [asked at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980613/does-google-crawl-https-links), but it doesn't have good references.

Does Googlebot crawl HTTPS?  (Please provide references.)

Comment: Not too sure this was needed? The SO question has an accepted answer which is correct - regardless of the need for an official source when Tim's answer below clearly demonstrates that secure pages are crawled. You've also gone on to answer this same question [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54837/12183).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is simple to demonstrate: A [Google search for inurl:https](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inurl%3ahttps&oq=inurl%3ahttps) yields 8.2 billion results.